# Accidentally deleted the Contest folder inside /usr/share/backgrounds

Tags: data-recovery, desktop-background

I accidentally deleted the contest folder from inside /usr/share/backgrounds and now I'm stuck with the static wallpaper option. I can't even seem to find it inside the trash bin. It happened while I was using nautilus. Is there a way to recover that folder? Actually, what I need is the precise.xml file which was inside it. If there is no way to recover that folder, can somebody just please post the script of that precise.xml file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
<background>
  <starttime>
    <year>2009</year>
    <month>08</month>
    <day>04</day>
    <hour>00</hour>
    <minute>00</minute>
    <second>00</second>
  </starttime>
<!-- This animation will start at midnight. -->
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Twilight_Frost_by_Phil_Jackson.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Twilight_Frost_by_Phil_Jackson.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Precise_Pangolin_by_Vlad_Gerasimov.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Precise_Pangolin_by_Vlad_Gerasimov.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Precise_Pangolin_by_Vlad_Gerasimov.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/The_Forbidden_City_by_Daniel_Mathis.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/The_Forbidden_City_by_Daniel_Mathis.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/The_Forbidden_City_by_Daniel_Mathis.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Winter_Morning_by_Shannon_Lucas.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Winter_Morning_by_Shannon_Lucas.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Winter_Morning_by_Shannon_Lucas.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Morning_Dew_by_Lars_Clausen.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Morning_Dew_by_Lars_Clausen.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Morning_Dew_by_Lars_Clausen.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Early_Blossom_by_Dh0r.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Early_Blossom_by_Dh0r.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Early_Blossom_by_Dh0r.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Delicate_Petals_by_lefthandgergo.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Delicate_Petals_by_lefthandgergo.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Delicate_Petals_by_lefthandgergo.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Golden_Bloom_by_Twinmama.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Golden_Bloom_by_Twinmama.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Golden_Bloom_by_Twinmama.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Tie_My_Boat_by_Ray_García.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Tie_My_Boat_by_Ray_García.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Tie_My_Boat_by_Ray_García.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Murales_by_Jan_Bencini.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Murales_by_Jan_Bencini.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Murales_by_Jan_Bencini.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Flocking_by_noombox.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Flocking_by_noombox.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Flocking_by_noombox.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/London_Eye_From_Beneath_by_Fernando_García.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/background/London_Eye_From_Beneath_by_Fernando_García.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/background/London_Eye_From_Beneath_by_Fernando_García.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Floorboards_by_Dawid_Huczyński.jpg</to>
  </transition>
   <static>
     <duration>1795.0</duration>
     <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Floorboards_by_Dawid_Huczyński.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Floorboards_by_Dawid_Huczyński.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Speaker_Weave_by_Phil_Jackson.jpg</to>
  </transition>
  <static>
    <duration>1795.0</duration>
    <file>/usr/share/backgrounds/Speaker_Weave_by_Phil_Jackson.jpg</file>
  </static>
  <transition>
    <duration>5.0</duration>
    <from>/usr/share/backgrounds/Speaker_Weave_by_Phil_Jackson.jpg</from>
    <to>/usr/share/backgrounds/Twilight_Frost_by_Phil_Jackson.jpg</to>
  </transition>
</background>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the ubuntu-wallpapers-precise package - if re-installing doesn't add back then download from here & extract the .deb, retrieve from folder /usr/share/backgrounds/contest/

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-wallpapers-precise